# Formula for the determinant of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices

The usual formula for determinant of an arbitrary matrix is given by:
$$\mbox{det}A = \sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}\epsilon_{\sigma}\prod_{k=1}^{n}a_{k,\sigma(k)}$$
where $\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}$ denotes the sum of every permutation $\sigma$ of the set $S_{n}:=\{1,...,n\}$ and $\epsilon_{\sigma}$ is the sign of the associate permutation $\sigma$.

Now, if $A = (a_{ij})$ be an $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, does
$$\mbox{det}A = \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}\epsilon_{\sigma}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}a_{\sigma(k)\sigma(k+1)}$$
hold?

Comment: Can you clarify how exactly you decided that this should be the formula for the determinant of a symmetric matrix?

Comment: I'm studying exterior algebras and I'm trying to prove that the Gaussian integral on these algebras is the determinant of the covariance matrix $A$, but my reasoning led to the right hand side of my second formula. I think this might make sense since the first formula you fixed the first index of $a_{k,\sigma(k)}$ in contrast with the second formula, where an extra factor $(2^{n}n!)^{-1}$ is considered.

Comment: As written, your current formula is clearly incorrect. For example, taking $A = I$ (the identity matrix) produces a $0$ on the right hand side

Comment: It's also dimensionally false (the right hand side is of degree $n-1$ in the entries of $A$, while the left hand side has degree $n$).

Comment: If $A$ is symmetric the RHS is zero. On the other hand if the matrix is antisymmetric, the RHS is a multiple of the Pfaffian whose square gives the determinant of $A$.